# R studio .csv table subset

Tags: r

I have loaded a table of this kind (but a lot bigger) in R (titles in caps):

https://postimg.org/image/66qmiayj5/

Does anyone know how I could make subsets of this table with:

- all rows with the value 'yes' for all the columns
- all rows with 'yes' in every column but one 'no'
- all rows with 'yes' in every column but two 'no'
- etc....

Comment: Reproducible data, like `dput` data or data that you create in a code block in the question are highly preferred to screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`. With your example:

```
df <- data.frame('GENES'=1:3,'STRAIN_1'=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),'STRAIN_2'=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),'STRAIN_3'=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
> df
  GENES STRAIN_1 STRAIN_2 STRAIN_3
1     1     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
2     2     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
3     3    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

You can subset the data set in the following way.

```
 > df[rowSums(df[,-1])==1,]
  GENES STRAIN_1 STRAIN_2 STRAIN_3
3     3    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE

> df[rowSums(df[,-1])==2,]
  GENES STRAIN_1 STRAIN_2 STRAIN_3
2     2     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
```

Note that `df[,-1]` is used to exclude the first column and that `rowSums(df[,-1])` retrieves the number of `TRUE` per rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `filter` command of `dplyr`. There are ways of doing this without creating a new column, but I wanted to make it obvious what's going on in this code.

```
# Create a sample data frame
df <- rbind(c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
c("Yes", "No", "No"),
c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"))
df <- data.frame(df)

# Create a column that counts the number of "No" values
df$count <- rowSums(df[-1] == "No")

# Filter for the appropriate number of "No"
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(count == 0) # All "Yes"
df %>% filter(count == 1) # One "No"
df %>% filter(count == 2) # Two "No"
```